# How to list latest timestamps files from partial duplicate name

Tags: bash, file

I have more than 10k  files like as given in below example. I would like to filter out partial duplicate i.e `123456` is common in all listed files which are consider to be duplicate and out of these duplicate files I need file of latest time stamps

```
   123456_20200425-012034.xml 
   123456_20200424-120102.xml
   123456_20200425-121102.xml
   234567_20200323-112232.xml
   123456_20200423-111102.xml --- consider that this file is having latest 
                                  timestamps out of all above duplicate file
```

How to do it using bash ?

Also output should have files which are not duplicate. It means out of 10K files few files are not duplicate those files should include in output.

Output is require like (latest timestamps files)

```
123456_20200423-111102.xml
234567_20200323-112232.xml
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so far and what challenges you are facing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because we can [assume that globs are sorted alphanumerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368318/does-the-bash-star-wildcard-always-produce-an-ascending-sorted-list), we can use a wildcard to iterate over the files and build a set of results:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# change INPUTDIR to your input directory
INPUTDIR=.
seen=
store=()

for file in "$INPUTDIR"/* ; do
    if [[ "$seen" != *"${file%_*}"* ]] ; then
        store+=( "$file" )
        seen="$seen ${file%_*}"
    fi
done

# results
echo "${store[@]}"
```

**Explanation:**

1. Iterate over all files in a directory.
2. Get the filename before the first underscore (i.e. `123456`). If we've haven't it before (i.e. `"$seen" != *"${file%_*}"*`), add it to our list of files to store. If we have seen it before, skip the file.
3. Print the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this:

```sh
list=$(ls | awk -F _ '{print $1}' | uniq)

for i in $list
do
  mv "$(find . -type f -name "$i*" -print | sort -n -t _ -k 2 | tail -1)" ../destination
done
```

1) Stored uniq files in list

2) Executed list file in to loop, find latest timestamp file and move it to destination folder

Comment: This probably works fine here, but it's generally bad practice to iterate over the output of `ls`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29